# Novel about a dying man able to travel through time in his ancestors' bodies during his near-death experience

Tags: story-identification, novel, time-travel, reincarnation

I'm looking for a novel read before 1992, so probably written in the 80s.

Here are the elements I remember:

- The main character is dying, and the plot follows him nearing death. Overall it may have read as a near-death experience of sorts.
- The setting is Earth, current world and history (no dystopia, and no major variation on the course of history as a whole.)
- As he is dying, 'present' time slows down, and he is able to travel through time in his ancestors bodies, with whom he shares DNA, so kind of a form of reincarnation. The ancestors do not realize they are 'occupied'.
- He encounters his female lover time and again, and they are at least able to swap bodies once (I think because of some common ancester.)
- The time periods he travels in range from antiquity to current time. One of the scenes is set during the French revolution. The plot may have been centered around their romance.
- Some of the bodies/persons he occupies may have been famous.
- I think it was a standalone novel
- I read it in French, but I think it was from an American author.

The closest plot I have found described here is:
[Novel about reincarnated lovers across history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105279/novel-about-reincarnated-lovers-across-history).
The author of the question has not confirmed the answer.

I've discarded:

- "My name is Memory", because it's too recent
- "Replay" (the character doesn't relive his own life, and the plot spans History)
- "Redshift" (no French revolution)
- "Daggerspell" (no magic in the book)

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Good first question. If anyone correctly identifies the novel you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: I read this, at least 25 years ago, let me see what I can remember

Comment: The book opens with a woman fleeing up a lighthouse - apparently in fear - as a large brutish man chases her. The main character lives in a horrible post apocalyptic society. The elderly are euthanized when they can no longer work, but are given "happy" drugs so they willing go to their deaths (I think they burn in a furnace). Everyone takes prescribed drugs, it's the only way society can function. There's some fight or disturbance in a lab, the main character is fatally wounded, but the cocktail of drugs in his system sends him time skipping through his ancestors lives.

Comment: At one point, when he loses track of the woman he meets he spends time "living" through his ancestors deaths, because he's depressed. The "method" of time travel is actually re-experiencing RNA encoded memories of ones ancestors (how was the memory of the deaths passed on? the "science" wasn't the best in this novel). I believe the novel title had the word "memory" in it.

Comment: Niiiice yes, that's the one !
*Memories* by Mike Mc Quay
I remembered the silvery cover of the french translation, which is typical of the 'Ailleurs & Demain' collection by Robert Laffont Edition.
Crossmatched with 'Memoire' in the title and, bingo ! I'll re-read that one and confirm the answer :)
Thank you so much !!!

Comment: I think you should self answer this question! I remembered so much of this novel and have spent a good hour trying to find it but couldn't! 

Answer (score 1):

The name of the book is *[Memories](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/921002.Memories)* by Mike Mcquay. *Mémoire* in French at the *livre de poche*. Hope this helps ;)

[image: Front cover of Memories]

> David Wolf is an embittered psychiatrist on the verge of an unimaginable journey. From one hundred decades in the future a woman called Silv arrives to seek David's help. One of Silv's murderous soldiers has traveled to the distant past of Napoleon's era and now has the power to manipulate the future. David and Silv must embark on an awesome quest to bring this man under control - before the very fabric of reality is torn to shreds.
> Memories is a sweeping, multi-layered odyssey filled with stunning imagery, breathtaking intensity and high drama.

[image: Cover of Mémoire]

> Un voyage dans le temps peut être aussi un voyage dans la mémoire.
> La mémoire des autres, la mémoire des siècles passés.
> Projetés d'un avenir inconcevablement éloigné, Hersh le soldat et Silv la savante tourbillonnent dans le temps, errant d'un corps à l'autre.
> Hersh est un guerrier fou. Y a-t-il pour lui destin plus attirant que celui de Bonaparte ?
> Mais s'il allait changer l'histoire ?
> David Wolf, psychiatre du XX e siècle, saura-t-il, comme Silv l'espère, ramener Hersh à la raison ? Et à son époque ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you [edit] some details into your answer that explain how this matches the question?